# Revoke all on schema

Tags: postgresql

I try add audit trigger for table in BD. I find example on [GitHub](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql). But I dont understand why author use this construction after create schema and table

```
CREATE SCHEMA audit;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA audit FROM public;
```

And for table:

```
REVOKE ALL ON audit.logged_actions FROM public;
```

What the aim of using `REVOKE` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `REVOKE` is pointless, because the default permissions on a new schema only allow the owner (the user that ran `CREATE SCHEMA`) to use it. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html):

> No privileges are granted to `PUBLIC` by default on tables, table columns, sequences, foreign data wrappers, foreign servers, large objects, schemas, tablespaces, or configuration parameters.

I can only assume that the `REVOKE` is a safety measure, in case the user who runs `CREATE SCHEMA` has changed the default privileges as follows:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT ... ON SCHEMAS TO PUBLIC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Revoke removes access permissions to an object.

it means only specific users that you will grant permission to them can access the audit scheme / logged_actions table.

"The key word PUBLIC refers to the implicitly defined group of all roles."